# Auto Generating Structure Member Names in C

Tags: c, struct, structure

I've recently been introduced to **struct** and in experimenting, I encountered a problem that I can't seem to find a solution for.

I want to create a structure with several members but I want the names for each member to be automatically generated to avoid tedious process of doing this manually. So far I have my structure and a function which I want to use to create a member.

STRUCT

```
struct Customers
{
    char name[30];
    int age;
}
```

PROTOTYPE

```
void newCustomer(Customers *Customer);
```

FUNCTION

```
void newCustomer(Customers *Customer)
{   
    char gender;
    int age;

    scanf_s("%c", 1, &gender);
    scanf_s("%d", &age);

    Customer->gender = gender;
    Customer->age = age;
}
```

MAIN

```
int main()
{
    int noOfCustomers;
    int i = 0;

    printf("How many customers will you be entering? : ");
    scanf_s("%d", &noOfCustomers);

    for(i = 0; i < noOfCustomers; i++)
    {
        Customers i;
        newCustomer(&i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Basically I want to do something like this... where each member is automatically represented by an ID or number. I do understand that the above example won't work because **i** is being declared locally within the loop as a sructure member and not an int but I want to know if there is a method of achieving this.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Is this an array? As in customers[0], customers[1], ...?

Comment: Do you mean "instance" rather than "member"?

Comment: Minor issue (well compared with the question) but in `Customer->gender`, `gender` is not defined in your struct.

Comment: `scanf_s("%c", 1, &gender);` ---> `scanf_s("%c", &gender, 1);`

Comment: Making people count is bad; much better to provide a way to say "I'm done" than to make them say "I'm going to enter 3 customers" first.   However, while you're still learning, asking first seems to be the standard way of doing business.

Comment: @EnricoGranata No, it's not an array.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Maybe... I read "member" somewhere but I guess "instance" is the correct term - thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @PeterM Good spot. I removed some properties before posting to make it shorter and clearer but it appears that I kept "gender" rather than "name".

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Is that the correct way of writing it? Thank you.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I chose to use a counting method just for easier practising but thanks for clarifying that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use static integer variable, call `itoa` to convert it to string, and then, increment.